# Serialize Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Could there appear some problems if I serialize a with Zend_Form created form and does this help much in view of the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about you Zend_Form performance (must be a huge form), then use Zend_Cache and insted of `new My_Form_Something()` use `$cache->load('My_Form_Something');` (see manual for Zend_Cache). But the main performance bottleneck is the form rendering. That can be overcome using `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Class` I guess...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question at all..

Serialization in performance will not help at all. You (or your engine) must deserialize that data anyway.

Comment: Yes, I must unserialize it later, but is that serialization/unserialization faster than create every time a new Zend_Form-Class?

Comment: If you want to serialize whole Zend_Form object - it's not a fast way.
If you have some data you fill out every time, you cat serialize only that data - but if form is clean, it has no sense to serialize anything.